# Why does bash ignore SIGTERM?

Tags: bash, signals

Sometimes when I want to logout quickly I do `kill -15 -1`. I've noticed that bash is ignoring SIGTERM.

I wonder **what's the rationale for such bash behavior**?

It's not very UNIX'y to ignore SIGTERM without a good reason, isn't it?

**UPDATE:**

same (no)effect for all:

```
$ kill -TERM $$
$ type kill
kill is a shell builtin
$ command kill -TERM $$
$ /bin/kill -TERM $$
```

**UPDATE2:**

From [man bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc24):

> When bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores
>   SIGTERM

So it's done on purpose. But why?

Comment: Which kill are you using? `/bin/kill` or the shell builtin? If the latter, I'm guessing that the shell won't kill itself with its own builtin.

Comment: @terdon: I used builtin, but I don't think that's the reason to not to kill it self.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer I am more interested in your rationale behind logging in such a manner.

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi: I was afraid that question... It's when I'm too lazy to move my hand from a keyboard to mouse and want to logout/login from X session. :-)

Comment: @MichałŠrajer as for your update, do not overthink it, probably bash ignores killing itself when it is interactive to prevent doing just that :)

Comment: If you want to logout quickly then use Ctrl+d

Comment: @YoMismo: "logout from X session"

Comment: @MichałŠrajer: Ctrl-Alt-Backspace does this for me on Xorg... you might have to enable it in xorg.conf, though.

Comment: When you say `-1`, I assume your not actually meaning PGID 1, is it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, this isn't specific to bash. ATT ksh, dash and zsh behave the same way: they ignore SIGTERM and SIGQUIT during command line edition; as for mksh, it also doesn't quit but treats them like SIGINT.

Both the ksh manual and the bash manual justify ignoring SIGTERM in these terms:

> so that `kill 0` does not kill an interactive shell

`kill 0` kills all processes in the [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) that the shell is in¹. In a nutshell, the process group consists of all the processes running in the foreground on a terminal, or all the processes in a background or suspended job.

More precisely, this is what happens in modern shells with [job control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)). In such shells, `kill 0` wouldn't be useful, as the shell would be in a process group of its own. Older shells (or modern shells after [`set +m`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html)) did not create process groups for background commands. So you could use the command `kill 0` to kill all background commands without getting logged out.² Thus the `kill 0` rationale looks like an old one which is no longer justified nowadays but kept for backward compatibility.

However there are other similar situations where making the shell immune is useful. Consider the case where you have processes hogging a terminal and you want to kill them without getting logged out. Many systems have a tool like [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) which let you kill the processes running on a terminal. You can run `pkill -t $TTY` or `pkill -QUIT -t $TTY` to kill all processes that are running on the current terminal, except the shell which ignores the signal.

A shell normally goes away either when the user exits it (with a command like `exit` or `logout`), or when its terminal signals the end of the input (the user can cause this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) or goes away altogether. In this last case, the shell receives the signal SIGHUP, and it doesn't ignore that one.

For your use case of logging out of an X session, `kill -15 -1` will do it, since it kills the terminal emulator which causes the shell to receive SIGHUP. It's in fact enough to kill the X server, but that requires finding its process ID. If you want the same command to work on a text session, you can use `kill -15 -1; exit`. That's quite a dangerous command to have at your fingertips anyway.

¹  <sub>This doesn't seem to be mentioned in shell manuals as a rule; it's a feature of the underlying system call. It is mentioned explicitly in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/kill.html).</sub> 
²  <sub>Nowadays, to do that, run `jobs -l` to see a list of jobs with their process group ID, then `kill -123 -456 …` to kill the process groups.</sub>

Comment: When you say `-1`, I assume your not actually meaning PGID 1, is it ?

Comment: @JohanBoulé For `kill` (both the system call and the shell command), pid=-1 is a special value, not a pgid. It means all processes that the caller is allowed to signal (from root: all processes; otherwise all processes with the same uid) except that the process won't signal itself.

Answer (score 6):

This might answer your question:

> When Bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores
>   SIGTERM (so that ‘kill 0’ does not kill an interactive shell), and
>   SIGINT is caught and handled (so that the wait builtin is
>   interruptible). When Bash receives a SIGINT, it breaks out of any
>   executing loops. In all cases, Bash ignores SIGQUIT. If job control is
>   in effect (see Job Control), Bash ignores SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, and
>   SIGTSTP.
>
> Non-builtin commands started by Bash have signal handlers set to the
>   values inherited by the shell from its parent. When job control is not
>   in effect, asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT in addition
>   to these inherited handlers. Commands run as a result of command
>   substitution ignore the keyboard-generated job control signals
>   SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, and SIGTSTP.
>
> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP. Before exiting,
>   an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or
>   stopped. Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive the
>   SIGHUP. To prevent the shell from sending the SIGHUP signal to a
>   particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the
>   disown builtin (see Job Control Builtins) or marked to not receive
>   SIGHUP using disown -h.
>
> If the huponexit shell option has been set with shopt (see The Shopt
>   Builtin), Bash sends a SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login
>   shell exits.
>
> If Bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for
>   which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the
>   command completes. When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command
>   via the wait builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has
>   been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an
>   exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is
>   executed.

**SOURCE**: [The GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html)

Comment: I quoted this in my update2. Man states that bash is doing so, but does not explain why such decision. The question remains - why?