# Is it possible to kill another user's process using sudo privileges?

Tags: linux, kill

I have sudo privileges on my home desktop running Fedora 22. I created a newuser with `sudo useradd newuser` and `sudo passwd newuser`. I then logged in as this newuser with `su newuser`, then switched back to myself with `su dwayne`.

I tried to delete the new user with `userdel -r mewuse`r, but I got a message

```
userdel: user newuser is currently used by process 6415
```

p.s.: 6415 shows newuser is in a bash shell which makes sense since I logged in to the bash shell as newuser with `su newuser`. And here is where my question comes from, I tried `sudo kill 6415` but it doesn't work nor does it give me any error message. Without an error you would think it all went as planned. I read the manpage for `kill(2)` but I did not find anything related to using `sudo` to kill a process. Is it possible to kill another users process with `sudo` or would I need to be logged in as root?

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be with `sudo`, but with process 6415 ignoring SIGTERM.

Comment: Related: [Why does bash ignore SIGTERM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185903/why-does-bash-ignore-sigterm)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to kill a users process with `kill`. You will have to specify the `-9` argument so it sends a `SIGKILL` signal.

Example: `sudo kill -9 6415`

> Is it possible to kill another users process with sudo or would I need to be logged in as root?

Please note that when you are using `sudo`, you are in fact calling that command as `root`.

Comment: absolutely perfect. That works. thankyou. I will need to look into kill flags a little more.

Comment: @Dwayne, Glad to have helped! `man kill` will show and give an explanation of all the signals that can be sent with `kill`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply log out of the new user account (first logging out of the second `dwayne` session that you go to via `su dwayne`. That will get you back to your initial session, at which point you should be able to `sudo userdel newuser` without problems.

Comment: Yes that worked and I was able to delete the newuser, but I am still wondering about the functionality of killing another users process with sudo priveleges?

Comment: You can do so, yes - in this case, the process probably didn't respond to the `kill` signal because it "knew" it was active and shouldn't die. You can also try a `kill -9 <pid>` which is a more forceful "die NOW!" order than a simple `kill <pid>`.